# Babelbib: combine bababbrv-lf and babunsrt-lf

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

I am using babelbib in order to generate my bibliography. However, it won't satisfy all my needs. I just want the entrys to be formatted like

> [1] Knuth, D. and Torvalds, L.: We didn't write anything together etc.
>
> [2] Abraham, A. and Barbara, B.: Our entry is not at the first place

So it has to fulfill:

- Order items as they appear within the text (and use numbers)
- Abbreviate names
- Names must all be in the order of "lastname, firstname"

I was using either

```
\bibliographystyle{bababbrv-lf}

\bibliographystyle{babunsrt-lf}
```

Each one only achieves 2 of the 3 points above. How can I get the whole thing to work? Below, you see a minimal working example, compiled with

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

### mwe.tex

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{One}
    Once, Lastname1 Firstname1 wrote a story~\cite{randomGuyStory}. And so did Derpina Derp~\cite{randomDerpinaStory}.
    \backmatter
    \bibliographystyle{babunsrt-lf}
%    \bibliographystyle{bababbrv-lf}
    \bibliography{mwebib}
\end{document}
```

### mwebib.bib

---

```
@article{randomDerpinaStory,
  title={The Story of tl;dr},
  author={Derp, Derpina and Herp, Herpington},
  journal={Journal of Sunday-workers},
  volume={284},
  number={46},
  pages={31548--31554},
}
@MASTERSTHESIS{randomGuyStory,
    author = {Lastname1, Firstname1 and Lastname2, Firstname2 and Lastname3, Firstname3},
    title = {Cool Story Bro},
    school = {Random University},
    year = {2012}
}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file `babunsrt-lf.bst` to your working directory and rename this file e.g. `mybabunsrt-lf`

After this change the function `format.names` to the following definition:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 >
      {
        s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ lastnamefont
        s nameptr "{,~jj}{,~f{.\btxfnamespaceshort }.}{~vv}" format.name$ *
        't :=
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t namefont * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "\btxandcomma {}" * }
                'skip$
              if$
              s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                { " " "\btxetalshort {.}" etalfont * * }
                { " \btxandshort {.}\ " * t namefont * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        {
          s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ lastnamefont
          s nameptr "{,~jj}{,~f{.\btxfnamespaceshort }.}{~vv}"
          format.name$ * namefont
        }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

After this modification I got the following result:

> [image]

Comment: thank you, works fine :-) I'm really stunned, that you cannot achieve this with a small parameter…

Comment: @Vincent: Than you have to use biblatex ;-)