# Highlight a specific author name in bibliography using babelbib

Tags: bibtex, babel

I want to highlight (more precisely make bold) a specific author name in bibliography using `bibtex`. There are several answers to this question, like
[this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86284/how-to-emphasize-some-author-names-using-bibtex), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47657/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography-continue), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91257/underline-different-authors-in-the-bibliography-by-hacking-bst-file) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/underline-my-name-in-the-bibliography). However, I'm using the `babelbib` package, and the previous solutions hack the plain style. I think that the solution that is closer to what I try to do is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33379/51724), however I'm not familiar with the language used to write bst files, in order to properly modify it.

For other reasons I have patched the `babunsrt-lf` style to show only the author initials and I the author name I want to highlight has the form `Lastname, {\relax Th}eo`

The patched version of `FUNCTION {format.names}` is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118361/51724).

**Edit:** Adding a MWE after @uT5r asked

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@CONFERENCE{CB:EPS36,
author      = {\textbf{Lastname, {\relax Th}eo} and Coauthor, John},
title       = {Some poster},
booktitle   = {36 Conference},
address     = {City},
year        = {2009},
pages       = {1015-1018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[francais,greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{english}
\setbtxfallbacklanguage{english}
\begin{document}
bla
\bibliographystyle{bababbrv-lf}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is quite the manual, and simply, solution, but would it be possible simply to manually open your .bib file and do a *find and replace*?

Say you want to make ``Bleeker, Marjo'' bold. You simply open your .bib file, search for `Bleeker, Marjo`, replace it with `\textbf{Bleeker, Marjo}`, and compile your .tex.

[image: \textbf{Bleeker, Marjo}]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{janssen1996evaluation,
  title={Evaluation of the DNA fingerprinting method AFLP as a new tool in bacterial taxonomy},
  author={Janssen, Paul and Coopman, Renata and Huys, Geert and Swings, Jean and \textbf{Bleeker, Marjo} and Vos, Pieter and Zabeau, Marc and Kersters, Karel},
  journal={Microbiology},
  volume={142},
  number={7},
  pages={1881--1893},
  year={1996},
  publisher={Soc General Microbiol}
}
@article{vos1995aflp,
  title={AFLP: a new technique for DNA fingerprinting},
  author={Vos, Pieter and Hogers, Rene and \textbf{Bleeker, Marjo} and Reijans, Martin and Van de Lee, Theo and Hornes, Miranda and Friters, Adrie and Pot, Jerina and Paleman, Johan and Kuiper, Martin and others},
  journal={Nucleic acids research},
  volume={23},
  number={21},
  pages={4407--4414},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=100, natbib=true, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\citet[1229]{vos1995aflp} has argued that $y$. Second, \citep[1229]{janssen1996evaluation} also show $m$ and $x$ \citet{vos1995aflp,janssen1996evaluation}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried this it works as in your example. However, when using a style with initials as first name, this solution keeps the whole name. I also tried different combinations of `\textbf` as `\textbf{Bleeker}, \textbf{Marjo}`, `\textbf{Bleeker}, \textbf{M}arjo`,  `\textbf{Bleeker, \textbf{M}\textbf{arjo}`, but nothing worked.  


I also noticed that you use biblatex, which does not seem to work with babelbib...  

The only solution I see now is to edit the .bst file itself...

Comment: @Theo, would it be possible for you to post a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can use the highlight command in *.bib source file. However I was able to highlight specific parts of the citation by adding \hl{} command to every single line of the citation information:

```
@article{StephenPark,
  title={\hl{Integration of biological kinetics and computational fluid dynamics to model the growth of Nannochloropsis salina in an open channel raceway}},
  author={\hl{Park, Stephen and Li, Yebo}},
  journal={\hl{Biotechnology and bioengineering}},
  volume={\hl{112}},
  number={\hl{5}},
  pages={\hl{923--933}},
  year={\hl{2015}},
  publisher={\hl{Wiley Online Library}}
}
```

which gives the following result:
[image]

you can remove the `\hl{}` command from any of the citation parts.

Comment: As fa i understand question, your answer doesn't help OP.

Comment: This would have serious impact on the sorting of authors.

Comment: I haven't had any problems in sorting the authors names. Whay would it impact that?

Comment: I wanted to highlight a reference paper on .bib file, and I got your answer with an example. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm often trying to do the same thing and what's just occurred to me is that as I have a separate `.bib` file for my publications and one for general references, I could define a command like `\authoremph` that does the kind of highlighting whatever powers-that-be want, e.g., with `\textbf` or `\underline`, and make sure every time my name appears, have it as `\authoremph{me}` in my `.bib` file.

If `\authoremph` isn't defined, then use `\newcommand\authoremph[1]{#1}` in the document preamble or `\newcommand\authoremph[1]{\textbf{#1}}` if I'm, e.g., writing a grant...

Testing it out - works beautifully! (Ok I know, I have to now have an extra line in my preamble in everything, but I use Sublime Text 3 and I can just put it in my "paper" template.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a working (minimal) example that highlights what you achieve. It's far better than describing it.